# Drupal Views question

Tags: drupal, view

I want to display a different set of 2 or 3 images in a block on each page.  So far, I have:

- Added images to each page using CCK and filefield.
- Removed the images from $content.
- Created a view with node ID (Nid) as the argument, and added the field created with CCK, and added display type of Block.

When I try the Live Preview, it will display all the images for all pages in the block.  When I enter the Node ID variable, it adds a where clause to the sql query and displays the correct images for that page.

How (where) do I set it up so that the view recognizes that it is on Node 3 and displays only the images for Node 3.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "How (where) do I set it up so that the view recognizes that it is on Node 3 and displays only the images for Node 3." -- you can do this by clicking on the settings for the Nid argument in Views. Under `Action to take if argument is not present:` choose `Provide Default Argument`. In that, choose `Node ID from URL`
2. Position your block in the appropriate region (left sidebar, right sidebar etc). Make sure the visibility settings of the block are such that it only appears at paths that match `node/*`